# Yii CGridview hide rows

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I have three rows in my yii CGridview and having two type of user logins.I have to hide one of the three rows depending on the type of user.Please help.

Comment: The data for the grid view typically comes from a data provider. Modify the code that creates the data provider or its data source to behave differently based on the login type.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Conditional statements like this:

```
public function newsearch()
{
    $id= Yii::app()->user->id;
    if($id = Your conditon){
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        Your Criteria to display
    } else {
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        Your Criteria to display
    }
    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

And Call this dataprovider in your GridView data provider.

Answer (score 1):

in your model add public static method
for example:

```
class Post extends CActiveRecord {

    public function tableName() {

        return 'posts';
    }

    public function rules() {

        return array();
    }

    public function attributeLabels() {

        return array();
    }
```

...

```
    public static function rulesUser() {
        if ( Yii::app()->user->id = 1 ) {
            return True;
        } else {
            return False;
    }  
}
```

add in your gridview for row:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', 
    array(
'id' => 'posts-grid',
'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
'filter' => $model,
'emptyText' => '',
'columns' => array(
        'id',
        'title',
        'post',
        'date_create',
                    array(
                    'name' => 'status',
                    'visible' => Posts::rulesUser(),
                     )
        array(
        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
    )
);
```

Comment: can you explain this a little bit more?

Comment: i must add that you have a typo.. is `if ( Yii::app()->user->id == 1 ) {`.. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

or add in model

```
public $visible = True;
```

in you search add if or switch

```
public function search()
{
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
     ...
    if (any if){
$this->visible = 1;
    }
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
}
```

in your gridview

...

```
array(              
'name'     => 'value',
'visible'=>$model->visible,
)
```

...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the task by conditioning the  `CDbCriteria` as follows,

```
if(!Yii::app()->session["admin"])
{
   $criteria->condition='t.unique_id!="i-8874c6e3"';
}
```

Thanks all.